# To control python versions or update to a newer version?

Tags: python

this is important for me. As you know python is very important to linux systems. And in many distros both python2 and python3 have come installed. That's very good! But in debian based distros both python versions are outdated. And it is not simple to update python like other programs. Therefore please advise me about this two points, which option is better way:

1. Upgrading existing python versions to a newer versions
2. Or through various programs to install python version you want and control them. (using pythonbrew-like program)

Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't want to _replace_ existing python versions as that may expose bugs in various system utilities.  So, install side-by-side (python is designed forthis) or consider upgrading to a newer version of your distribution.  Debian Jessie, for example, has python3.4.2 available and you can't get much more recent than that.

Comment: I would recommend supporting previous versions up to a certain degree and simply have both python2 and python3 installed. For python2 I usually support 2.6 and up although for some projects I've switched to 2.7 and up. For python3 I usually support 3.3 and higher. Having that said, it's fairly trivial to have a project support both python 2 and 3 at the same time if you write it like that from the start.

Comment: ok 1. option is not preferrred way. But how do you install various python versions to your local system without influencing your older versions ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind-of unclear, but this is my answer for you. It seems that you want to know whether to turn to a third party app to install a newer version of python, or you want to use apt-get to install it. That question, I feel, is answered by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu).

Comment: No, in the second option I mentioned to install python using pythonbrew like program but pythonbrew is not supported any more I think. If I install python from source as in your link will that effect my older versions?

Comment: if by older versions, you mean deleting 2.x, then no, it will just upgrade it to the latest 2.x version of python, and python code is compatible from 2.x to 2.x, just not 2.x to 3.x